# How to stop class database file getting created multiple times when using moor?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-moor, moor

I'm getting this error:

> flutter: WARNING (moor): It looks like you've created the database
> class AppDatabase multiple times. When these two databases use the
> same QueryExecutor, race conditions will occur and might corrupt the
> database.

```
class AppDatabase extends _$AppDatabase {
  AppDatabase() :  super(_openConnection());
  int get schemaVersion => 1;
  

}
```

But I want to have multiple instance of Db class.
Is there any way to create multiple instance of Db class?

Thanks

Comment: Does this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66040688/10157127) solve the issue ?

Comment: no it did not, I could not understand what to do